# Appending the removed elements to a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am removing `J1` from `J` but I also want to append the two. I present the current and expected output.

```
J=[2, 6, 9, 10]
J1=[6,10]
for i in range(0,len(J1)): 
    J.remove(J1[i])
    J.append(J)
print(J)
```

The current output is

```
[2, 9, [...], [...]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[2, 6, 9, 10],[2,9]]
```

Comment: `print([J, J1])` would work in this case

Comment: Why in the expected output is nothing removed from the first nested list?

Comment: I have updated the expected output.

Comment: Why are you putting `J` inside `J`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l=[]
l.append(J)
l.append([x for x in J if x not in J1])

print(l)
#[[2, 6, 9, 10], [2, 9]]
```